Does bash abort on error work inside a function?
Please, observe:
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$ f(){ set -euo pipefail ; git statu; echo $?; } && f && echo OK ; set +euo pipefail
git: 'statu' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar commands are
        status
        stage
        stash
1
OK
mark@L-R910LPKW:~$

The command is f(){ set -euo pipefail ; git statu; echo $?; } && f && echo OK ; set +euo pipefail
My question is - why does the function f NOT abort right after failing to run git statu? Running the command clearly shows that git statu failed with exit code 1, but still proceeds further to echo $? instead of aborting as requested by set -e.

The function is run with its exit status tested (with &&), so errors aren't treated as exit-worthy. set -e is full of weird exceptions like this, and isn't even consistent between different versions of bash. See BashFAQ #105: "Why doesn't set -e (or set -o errexit, or trap ERR) do what I expected?"

Also see Bash Pitfalls #60 (set -euo pipefail).

This is well documented in the manual:

[When -e is set, t]he shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a while or until keyword, part of the test in an if statement, part of any command executed in a && or || list except the command following the final && or ||, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the command’s return status is being inverted with !.


If a compound command or shell function sets -e while executing in a context where -e is ignored, that setting will not have any effect until the compound command or the command containing the function call completes.

Your function does abort in a context where -e is not ignored. For example:
$ f(){ set -euo pipefail ; git statu; echo $?; }
$ ( f; echo OK )
git: 'statu' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar commands are
        status
        stage
        stash
$

